# Make gcc turn a sequence of BYTE comparisons into WORD/DWORD/QWORD instead

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization

I currently have the following:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
bool isZeroed(T const & num) {
    void const * ptr = std::addressof(num);
    uint8_t const * pos = static_cast<uint8_t const *>(ptr);
    uint8_t const * const endpos = pos + sizeof(T);
    for (;pos < endpos; ++pos)
    {
      if (*pos != uint8_t(0)) 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  return isZeroed(static_cast<uint64_t>(argc));
}
```

which produces on gcc 7 with -O3 this:

```
main:
        movsx   rdi, edi
        test    dil, dil
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-8], rdi
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-7], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-6], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-5], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-4], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-3], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-2], 0
        jne     .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rsp-1], 0
        sete    al
.L2:
        movzx   eax, al
        ret
.L9:
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L2
```

see https://godbolt.org/g/HWB3is

In my head I think it should be possible to collapse these BYTE comparisons into ones that take more bytes at a time like WORD/DWORD/QWORD.

Anyone know what I've done in the code that prevents the optimizer doing this or is this not possible in gcc?

Comment: I think the compiler forgets that all the bytes are known to be valid, and hence takes measures to not access extra memory except what is actually needed. The source code does not access `pos[1-7]` if `pos[0]` is not zero, and the compiler ensured that behavior. PS: `int` is not typically 64 bit, but maybe it is in your environment. In any case, the code is similar for 32 bit too.

Comment: So I need to access memory in larger chunks deliberately, because the compiler is also preserving the memory access pattern.

Comment: yes the compiler is doing what you told it to do, you want it to do something different, tell it...

Comment: Isn't this UB? Specially accessing an object through a pointer of an incompatible type (e.g. `*pos`). To be less standardese, structs can have paddings and padding don't need to be zero.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It's probably not undefined behaviour because accesses through `unsigned char` pointers is allowed to objects of any type, and `uint8_t` pretty much has to be `unsigned char` or not exist. The type used in the example, `uint64_t`, can't have any padding bits, but in general whether given a type, not just structures, has padding or not is implementation defined.

Comment: @RossRidge Good point! I forgot the min-max range imposed by the standard on the `unsigned char` type.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Jester's comment into account, I can do the following.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

template<typename CmpSizeType>
bool isZeroed(void const * & pos, size_t & bytesLeft) { 
  while (bytesLeft >= sizeof(CmpSizeType))
  {
    CmpSizeType const * posOfSize = static_cast<CmpSizeType const *>(pos);
    if ( *posOfSize != CmpSizeType(0)) return false;
    pos = posOfSize + 1;
    bytesLeft -= sizeof(CmpSizeType);
  }
  return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool isZeroed(T const & num) {  
  size_t bytesLeft = sizeof(T);
  void const * pos = std::addressof(num);
  if(!isZeroed<uint64_t>(pos,bytesLeft)) return false;
  if(!isZeroed<uint32_t>(pos,bytesLeft)) return false;
  if(!isZeroed<uint8_t>(pos,bytesLeft)) return false;
  return true;
}

struct T{
  int8_t  a1,b1,c1;
  int16_t a2;
  int32_t a3,b3,c3,c4;
  int64_t a4;
  int16_t a5;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  return 
    isZeroed(T{ 0,0,0,0,argc,0,0,0,0,0 }) &&
    isZeroed(static_cast<int8_t>(argc));
}
```

Gives QWORD compares instead:

```
main:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-56], xmm0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-48], edi
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rsp-48], 0
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0
        jne     .L6
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], 0
        jne     .L6
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rsp-32], 0
        jne     .L6
        xor     eax, eax
        test    dil, dil
        sete    al
        ret
.L6:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Comment: GCC is being silly here though, explicitly comparing zero to zero. Clang compiles it better - but in a way that defeats the purpose of the test.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle the case where the template argument `T`  might have a less strict alignment than `uint64_t` or `uint32_t`. It also doesn't handle the case where T might have padding. The compiler could've generated code where the fourth byte (and many other bytes) of the object created by `T{ 0,0,0,0,argc,0,0,0,0,0 }` wasn't initialized.

Answer (score -1):

When you tell the compiler to look at BYTE-sized chunks, it will do so. If you want it to look at DWORD- or QWORD-sized chunks, you need to ask it to do so. Something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
bool isZeroed(T const & num) {
    void const * ptr = std::addressof(num);
    uint8_t const * pos = static_cast<uint8_t const *>(ptr);
    uint8_t const * const endpos = pos + sizeof(T);
    for (;pos < endpos; pos += sizeof(uint64_t))
    {
      if (*reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(pos) != 0) 
        return false;
    }
    for (;pos < endpos; ++pos)
    {
      if (*pos != uint8_t(0))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We first loop through comparing QWORD-sized chunks to zero. If anything non-zero is found, then one of the BYTEs must have been non-zero, so return `false`. Then, we loop again to deal with any leftover BYTE-sized chunks.

This produces the code you want. Actually, even better—the compiler knows you're passing a QWORD-sized value to the template function, so it simply uses a `TEST` instruction:

```
main:
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    sete    al
    ret
```

If you use the GCC extension and pass an 128-bit integer value, the function is compiled to the following, which does two QWORD comparisons, as expected:

```
main:
    movsx   rdi, edi
    cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
    jne     .L3
    cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 0
    sete    al
.L2:
    movzx   eax, al
    ret
.L3:
    xor     eax, eax
    jmp     .L2
```

Note that this is *very* unsafe, as should be obvious from the `reinterpret_cast`. I also question the utility of this. Write template specializations for all of the integer sizes—there aren't that many, and you'll get better code without compromising safety. Or, if you're testing arbitrary chunks of memory, use `memcmp`—*e.g.*:

```
template<typename T>
bool isZeroed(T const & num) {
    void const * ptr = std::addressof(num);
    uint8_t temp[sizeof(T)] = { };
    return memcmp(temp, ptr, sizeof(T));
}
```